# Implementing Google Custom Search API in Apps Script

Tags: javascript, rest, google-apps-script, google-custom-search

I'm looking to write a program in Google apps script that keeps an instance of my CSE up to date by regularly posting an "annotations" XML file containing certain urls. I have a properly formatted XML file to be posted to the CSE, however I'm a little unclear about how to authorize the post using Apps Script's UrlFetchApp. Here's what I have so far:

```
  var userId = "my user ID";
  var cseID = "my custom search engine ID";
  var xml = an xml blob;
  var auth = ScriptApp.getOAuthtoken();
  var cseUrl = "http://cse.google.com/api/"+userId+"/annotations/"+cseID;

  var params = {
    "method"  : "POST",
    "contentType" : "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
    "payload" : xml,
    "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
    "Authorization" : "GoogleLogin auth=" + auth
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(cseUrl, params)
```

However I'm getting `<Error>You are not authorized to access this resource.  If you feel this is an error, try re-logging into your Google Account.</Error>` as the response. Should the "auth" variable in this case be the auth token I get from `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()`, or should that be the API key from the Google developer Dashboard?

I've been following their tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/api#create_annos), but I'm fairly new to using REST, so any pointers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your Authorization to the headers parameter in the params object.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#getRequest(String,Object)

Check the edit below.

```
var params = {
    "method"  : "POST",
    "contentType" : "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
    "payload" : xml,
    "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
    "headers":{"Authorization" : "GoogleLogin auth=" + auth}
  };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, one step closer, however I'm still getting "not authorized" errors. Do you happen to know what I should be passing to `auth`? I've tried both my API key and `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()` but neither seem to work.